# PyOpenGL :: OpenGL.error.NullFunctionError: Attempt to call an undefined function glutInit, check for bool(glutInit) before calling

Tags: python, opengl, visual-c++, pyopengl, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I'm following this very [easy guide](https://stackabuse.com/brief-introduction-to-opengl-in-python-with-pyopengl/) in order to make my first steps into PyOpenGL.

1. I installed `pip install PyOpenGL PyOpenGL_accelerate` , all good.
2. I tested the installation through the test code:

   import OpenGL.GL
   import OpenGL.GLUT
   import OpenGL.GLU
   print("Imports successful!") # If you see this printed to the console then installation was successful

all good

I now run this script:

```
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

w,h= 500,500
def square():
    glBegin(GL_QUADS)
    glVertex2f(100, 100)
    glVertex2f(200, 100)
    glVertex2f(200, 200)
    glVertex2f(100, 200)
    glEnd()

def iterate():
    glViewport(0, 0, 500, 500)
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    glLoadIdentity()
    glOrtho(0.0, 500, 0.0, 500, 0.0, 1.0)
    glMatrixMode (GL_MODELVIEW)
    glLoadIdentity()

def showScreen():
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
    glLoadIdentity()
    iterate()
    glColor3f(1.0, 0.0, 3.0)
    square()
    glutSwapBuffers()

glutInit()
glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA)
glutInitWindowSize(500, 500)
glutInitWindowPosition(0, 0)
wind = glutCreateWindow("OpenGL Coding Practice")
glutDisplayFunc(showScreen)
glutIdleFunc(showScreen)
glutMainLoop()
```

And the error I receive is `OpenGL.error.NullFunctionError: Attempt to call an undefined function glutInit, check for bool(glutInit) before calling`

So  i read a few guides online and they point to download the wheel from [here](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyopengl). So I go ahead and I download `PyOpenGL_accelerate‑3.1.5‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl` and `PyOpenGL‑3.1.5‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl` because I'm running `Python 3.8`

1. `pip install .\PyOpenGL_accelerate-3.1.5-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl` returns `PyOpenGL-accelerate is already installed with the same version as the provided wheel. Use --force-reinstall to force an installation of the wheel.`
2. `pip install .\PyOpenGL_accelerate-3.1.5-cp38-cp38-win_amd64.whl` returns `PyOpenGL-accelerate is already installed with the same version as the provided wheel. Use --force-reinstall to force an installation of the wheel.`

How can a so simple guide lead me to a so painful result?

How can I check if `Visual C++ 14.0 build tools` is installed. Maybe that is the only step I'm missing?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since "Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages" no longer exist (see [Christoph Gohlke's Windows Wheels site is shutting down by the end of the month](https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/vcaibq/christoph_gohlkes_windows_wheels_site_is_shutting/)), the following solution no longer works:

The _freeglut_ DLL is missing from the package.

Unistall "PyOpenGL":

```
pip uninstall pyopengl
```

Download the package wheel (e.g.: "PyOpenGL‑3.1.6‑cp311‑cp311‑win_amd64.whl") from, [Unofficial Windows Binaries for Python Extension Packages](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pyopengl) and install it:

```
pip install PyOpenGL‑3.1.6‑cp311‑cp311‑win_amd64.whl
```

---

Alternatively the wheels may be found here: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1mz7faVsrp0e6IKCQh8MyZh-BcCqEGPwx

---

If you don't find a wheel for your needs, you need to clone the [mcfletch/pyopengl](https://github.com/mcfletch/pyopengl) repository and install PyOpenGL from the repository (see also [PyOpenGL and PyOpenGL_Accelerate](https://github.com/mcfletch/pyopengl#pyopengl-and-pyopengl_accelerate)):

clone the repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/mcfletch/pyopengl
```

install *pyopengl* and *pyopengl_accelerate*:

```
cd pyopengl
pip install -e .
cd accelerate
pip install -e .
```