# Install PyOpenGL for Windows under Python 3.12

Tags: installation, pyopengl, python-3.12

I want to install PyOpenGL for Windows under Python 3.12.
The version on PyPI does not work properly (as the versions for 3.11 and before).
So, how can I install it?

I used to be able to download properly working wheels from 'Unoffical Binaries for Windows Extension Packages' ([https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/))
But this site is archived and not updated after mid 2022.

So, now my question is: How can I install a properly working version of PyOpenGL for Python 3.12 ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PyOpenGL :: OpenGL.error.NullFunctionError: Attempt to call an undefined function glutInit, check for bool(glutInit) before calling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65699670/pyopengl-opengl-error-nullfunctionerror-attempt-to-call-an-undefined-functio)

Comment: If you do not need glut you can just install it with pip (`pip install pyopengl pyopengl-accelerate`). Otherwise see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65699670/pyopengl-opengl-error-nullfunctionerror-attempt-to-call-an-undefined-functio/65699812#65699812

Comment: I do need glut, so I can't just install with pip.

Comment: You should prefer not to use glut, as it is outdated for decades. Use [glfw](https://pypi.org/project/glfw/) instead.

Answer (score 0):

The author of the "Unofficial Binaries ...", gave me a link to updated wheels (including for Python 3.12) for PyOpenGL and PyOpenGL-accelerate:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1mz7faVsrp0e6IKCQh8MyZh-BcCqEGPwx?usp=sharing
Although he warns that they might not be stable, they work for me.